# How to fetch SQLite list in a function in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart

I am making a contact list SMS sending app. I have used SQLite for CRUD functions and made it successfully and for messaging I am using Twillio. This is the Twillio function:

```
void sendSms() async {
    twilioFlutter.sendSMS(
        toNumber: 'number here', messageBody: "Here's how it looks like");
  }
```

where I have to put all the numbers.

I don't understand how I can bring the SQLite contact list I've made here in the function. My SQLite code is the exact same copied from here [SQLite Tutorial Code](https://www.codepolitan.com/mengakses-database-sqlite-dengan-flutter) In addition, my function of Twillio is in another file and if SQLite is not a good option and moving to Firestore CRUD will work. I am open to do that as well if anyone lets me know how.